# How can I extract value from a class in my main function?

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Solution {
public:
    string fun(string s) {
        
        return //value;
    }
};
int main(){
string s;
//get the value returned by the fun()
}
```

*How can I Extract a value returned by fun() in my main() function*

Comment: Note that stackoverflow is not an "introduction to C++ classes...". These basic things are explained in any beginner [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2):

This is very basic C++ programming, please read a book.
Anyway, you need:

1. to instanciate the class to get an object
2. call the method on the object

This way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Solution {
public:
    string fun() {      
        return "a string";
    }
};
int main(){
  Solution aSolution; // instanciate
  string s = aSolution.fun(); // call the method and catch the result
}
```

Comment: Definitely I will read books, and thanks a lot for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways, by making fun return the value you want it to, then you assign it to the s variable in main. Or you can use a reference in the function parameter, meaning you can pass it to the function, and then the function can change the value of the variable inside it.
Hope this helps!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Solution {
public:
    string fun(string str) {
        
        return str;
    }

    void fun2(string &str, string new_value) {
        str = new_value;
    }
};
int main(){

    Solution sol; // You need to initialize the Solution object
    string s = sol.fun("Value"); //fun returns the value you put into parameter, thus you assign that value to s
    std::cout << s << '\n'; //Prints Value

    sol.fun2(s, "Another Value"); //fun2's first parameter is a reference, meaning that the variable can be changed by the function without needing a return, 2nd parameter is the value that will be assigned. 
    std::cout << s << '\n'; //Prints "Another Value"

}
```

Comment: it's working, thanks...!